# Promotion code with Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django 1.3.3 application.  I've been asked to add a "promotion code" type of feature to it.  Basically when the user signs up for this one product (note: not at the time of user registration for the system), they can enter a promotion code (*IF* they have one) and it will give them a number of days for free.

Before being given this requirement, I had the enrollment page for this product as a simple ModelForm.  I have made the changes needed to the models and have added a foreign key field from the "member" model to the new promotion model.

- id (integer)
- promo_code models.CharField(max_length=20)
- number_of_days = models.IntegerField()

  ```
  def __unicode__(self):
      return u'{}'.format(self.promo_code)
  ```

When it add it to the form, it gives me a drop down box with all of the promotion codes.  But, that's not what I want.  I want them to have to have the code and enter it in a text box.  Then as a part of form validation, see if it's a valid code.  Remember, they may not have a code at all (so, I don't want them to just select from a list).

What's the best way to implement a requirement like this with a Django ModelForm?

Note: I know that I could back up and have a completely custom form, but I have the page working with a ModelForm already, and just need to add this functionality.

Comment: Correct me if wrong, how about making the promo code primary key and using a custom textbox widget for the promo code field.

Comment: @nims I like this idea.  It leads to some bloat in the database (int vs varchar in the member table), but it gets rid of the need for two fields and the unique index on promo_code.

Comment: @nims I implemented the solution you recommended.  If you will write it up as an answer, I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would exclude the foreign key field on the member model from the Form.

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        exclude = ('promo',)
```

Add an additional input element into the template for your promo code. Then do a bit of custom processing in your view -

```
def sign_up(request):
    #...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MemberForm(request.POST)
        if form.valid():
            obj = form.save()
            if 'promo_field' in request.POST:
                try:
                    obj.promo = Promotion.objects.get(pk=request.POST['promo_field'])
                    obj.save()
                except DoesNotExist:
                    pass # the code wasn't valid
    else:
        #...
```

If you're using generic view classes for your form editing then override the `form_valid()` method to add the promo code (with the pattern above). You'll be able to access the post data with `self.request.POST`.